# returning two largest values in an array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
int largest = 0;
int secondLargest = 0;   

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] > largest) {
        secondLargest = largest;
        largest = array[i];
    } else if(array[i] > secondLargest) {
        secondLargest = array[i];
    }
}


int[] array2 = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14};
```

I have this code that compares values in an array and returns the two biggest values.

I don't understand how  this loop walks through the array if the values are initialized to 0. I tried using debug in eclipse but I still do not understand what is going on?

Can somebody explain this in detail, step-by-step, what exactly happens here?

Comment: You're assuming all integers are positive. If they're all `-100` (for example), it'll return `0` as the largest.

Answer (score 1):

This code assumes that all the values in the array are positive integers.

If the array is initialized to zero, it will still walk through the array, but will not change the values.

If we go step by step:

- for loop reads element by element in the array.
- If the current element (`2`) is larger than the larger one we found (yet), (in the first run it's `0`. Hence first value (in this case `2`) is assigned to the `largest`.
- Then it saves the current largest (here `0`) as the `secondLargest`.
- Then it will jump to the next element (`4`), where it does the comparison again.
- Now it will assign `4` to the largest as `4 > 2`
- Hence `secondLargest` will be `2`.
- This will continue until the array ends.

Answer (score 0):

A more secure (in terms of negative numbers, etc.) and probably easier to understand solution would be to convert the array to a list, sort it in reverse order, and then just take the first two elements

```
int[] a = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14};
List<Integer> f = IntStream.of(a).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
f.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
System.out.println(f.get(0) +" - " + f.get(1));
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/FBEVA46814)